# I need to print line number along with the line content but I am getting line number and the content in 2 different lines

Tags: c, file-handling

```
main() 
{
     FILE *fp;
     char c;
     int count=1;
     fp=fopen("D:\file.txt","r");
     printf("%d ",count);
     c = fgetc(fp);
     while(c!=EOF) 
     {
         if(c=='\n')
         {
              count++;
              printf("\n%d",count);
         }
         putchar(c);
         c=fgetc(fp);
     }
     fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Note that `c` needs to be `int`, not `char`, otherwise your EOF test will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are also printing the newline you just read from the file,

Change

```
if(c=='\n') {
 count++;
 printf("\n%d ",count);
}
putchar(c);
```

to

```
if(c=='\n') {
 count++;
 printf("\n%d",count);
} else {
  putchar(c);
}
```

Alternativly, don't print the newline when you print the line number,

```
putchar(c);
if(c=='\n') {
  count++;
  printf("%d ",count);
}
```

You also have to change

```
char c;
```

to

```
int c;
```

getchar() returns an int, and EOF is a value that cannot be represented by a char.